# CustomPainter not painting at the correct position after device orientation changes

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to learn Flutter. I'm drawing a diagonal line using CustomPainter on a centered square container whenever the container is tapped. The CustomPainter draws the line correctly.

However the line changes its position when the device orientation changes and is no longer in the center of the container.

I'm using didChangeMetrics() to detect when device orientation changes and redrawing the line. But this time the line is not drawn in the center of the container as intended. However if the container is tapped again the line is drawn correctly. I'm calling the same function to draw the line at both the places didChangeMetrics and onTapDown.

I'm using the following code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Offset start = Offset.zero;
  Offset end = Offset.zero;
  double winLineWidth = 0;
  GlobalKey _containerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    _drawLine();
  }

  void _drawLine() {
    RenderBox box = _containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var _boxOffset = box.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    print(getBox.globalToLocal( Offset(_boxOffset.x, _boxOffset.y) ));
    var appBarHeight = 80;
    setState(() {
      start = Offset(_boxOffset.x, _boxOffset.y - appBarHeight);
      end = Offset(_boxOffset.x + 100, _boxOffset.y - appBarHeight + 100);
      print('$start $end');
      winLineWidth = 2;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Demo'),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (TapDownDetails tapDownDetails) {
                _drawLine();
              },
              child: Container(key: _containerKey,width: 100,height: 100,color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          CustomPaint(painter:WinLine(start: start, end: end, winLineWidth: winLineWidth),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WinLine extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  Offset start, end;
  double winLineWidth;

  WinLine({this.start, this.end, this.winLineWidth = 8}) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = winLineWidth;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawLine(start, end, _paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(WinLine oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

How do I get the CustomPainter to again redraw the line at the center of the container even after the device changes its orientation.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Solved it with this workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134559/4135133. But would still like an answer to the above if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to put your `drawLine` method inside a `FrameCallback` :

```dart
@override
void didChangeMetrics() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _drawLine();
  });
}
```